# "Bad element for masonry: undefined" why this error us occuring?

Tags: theme-development, masonry

I am developing a WordPress Theme using masonry. but it generates following error on index page

```
"Bad element for masonry: undefined"
```

and these two errors on single.php

```
"Bad element for masonry: undefined"
"Bad element for masonry: null"
```

Here is the code i am using in my theme

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

      // MASSONRY Without jquery
      var container = document.querySelector('#ms-container');
      var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector: '.ms-item',
        columnWidth: '.ms-item',
      });

    });

 $(function(){
          "use strict";
    var m = new Masonry($('.grid').get()[0], {
        itemSelector: ".masonary"
    });

});
```

is there any clue about this issue?

Comment: Better to ask at other Stack Exchange sites. JavaScript questions is off topic.